# Having trouble to split a file with text into seperate words

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, append, nltk

I have been trying to split a file with text into distinct words.
I tried using the iter method, the nltk module and just splits, but something doesn't add when i am trying to append the outcome to a list.
Maybe there is some problem with the syntax of my approaching the file.

```
txt = open(game_file)
print txt.read()

names = []
linestream = iter(txt.read())
for line in linestream:
    for word in line.split():
        names.append(word)
```

when I try to print the list names, i just get '[]'.

Comment: pls provide a short example for your files thx

Comment: Try it with `readlines` instead of `read`

Comment: the text file- i added /n instead of the drop line in the real file: 
line 111111 /n

line 222222 /n
line 333333 /n
asdasdasda /n
fghdghdh /n
cvbcvbcb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `txt.read()` you're already at the end of your file. So when you try to restart it, the file pointer is already at the end and it does not find anything.
Try to delete your 2nd line and it should work!

Also, you don't need to do `iter(txt.read())`,
`for line in txt` should work!

Comment: awsome. works now.
 didnt remember that read puts the pointer to the end..
but- if i put a for or iter on the txt again, it doesnt put the pointer at the beginning?
or because it's a file- we have to put it there manually.

Comment: Exactly, if you re-read it with a for loop for instance, it would be empty again. You have 2 ways to circumvent this issue:
1) You save the lines in an array at the beginning: lines = txt.readlines(). Then you can iterate over this list as many times as you want. The downside is that you need enough memory to store the file
2) You reopen the file each time you need to re-read it (with txt = open('file.txt'))

Answer (score 1):

Remove `print txt.read()`, you are iterating through empty opened file

Or make new variable `text = txt.read()` and do stuff with it

Answer (score 0):

Creating **"iter"** object of `_any_file_obj_.read()` returns iter object which iterates over every single character present in the file. Which is surely you dont want to acheive here as you want to split file text into distinct words.
If you want to get the every word form the text file, then you can follow the following approach.

```
word_list = []
txt = open(any_file)    # creating file object

for line in txt.readlines():
    if line:
        [word_list.append(word) for word in line.split()]
txt.seek(0)
```

The last line **txt.seek(0)** is very important.

**All this time, your code was giving empty list [] because the files current position after one full iteration was pointing at the end of file (EOF). _file_obj_.seek() can be used to return files current position to wherever you want in the opened file**

Comment: but what is the result if i iterate through it using this-
linestream = iter(txt.readlines()) ?
isn't the result of an iteration- a seperate line every time? or it gives back single characters?

Comment: Its a single character you get for every iteration. You see single character on separate line because you print them on console.